# Split a string into lines of n characters each

Tags: sed

Is it possible to split the string to lines of n characters each with sed? For example, I have a file in which the data is written in one line.

```
Index:0070;Done:0;Fixed:1;Index:0056;Done:1;Fixed:1;Index:0070;Done:1;Fixed:0;...
```

How to break a string into lines, 26 characters each?

Comment: `${str:pos:length}`?.

Comment: Alternatively insert a newline with GNU sed after every third semicolon: `sed -E 's/(([^;]*;){3})/\1\n/g' file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(.{26})/\1\n/g' file
```

Output:

```
Index:0070;Done:0;Fixed:1;
Index:0056;Done:1;Fixed:1;
Index:0070;Done:1;Fixed:0;
```

Comment: No need for parens just use `&` in the RHS in place of `\1`

Comment: Good idea. `sed -E 's/.{26}/&\n/g' file`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/./&\n/26;P;D' file
```